# Issue with multiple virtual hosts on dedicated server. 2nd VH won't respond, 1st one does

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I've got two virtual hosts setup and enabled using a2ensite.

It's Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS, Apache2, etc.

So there's two config files in /etc/apache2/sites-available and their respective symlinks in sites-enabled.

The problem is only the first can be accessed. I'm using name-based vhosts, so multiple domain names pointing to one dedicated IP. When the 2nd added domain is accessed, there's no response from the server at all, not even an error code. The domain does resolve to the correct IP. Visiting the first domain, or the IP directly shows the first vhost site.

Here's the two configs changed to example1 and example2.

```
<VirtualHost example1.co.uk:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example1.co.uk"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.co.uk
    ServerName example1.co.uk
    <Directory "/var/www/example1.co.uk">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost example2.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example2.com"
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example2.com
    ServerName example2.com
    <Directory "/var/www/example2.com">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Allowoverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been working on this issue for days and exhausted my knowledge. It doesn't seem like a typical misconfiguration to me. I hope you can help. Thanks.

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Any relevant log file entries? Is the browser aware of the address change or is it still using a cached DNS entry with the old IP address?

Comment: Hi, Sven. Both the working domain and the 2nd domain resolve to my IP. If I tracert the newly added domain it ends up at my server, but the server does not respond. The domain was added to my DNS to point to the dedicated IP a while ago, It's just that I've only just setup the 2nd virtual host for this domain.

Comment: I'll check the error and access logs. brb

Comment: Can you verify that the client is issuing an HTTP =>1.1 request? HTTP 1.0 cannot handle virtual hosts.

Comment: I've checked the error log, access log and "other_vhosts_access.log" and there's no mention of my newly added domain.

Comment: @quadruplebucky Yes, the response is Error 111: Connection refused

Comment: @i-CONICA I should have been clearer, do you have a traffic capture of the network conversation?

Comment: From the client or server end? The tracert from my local client makes every hop across the net until it reaches my dedicated server IP which doesn't respond to the request. The server doesn't acknowledge the request at all. I've not got ntop or anything running. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to access the second site using telnet instead of a browser? (Example: `telnet example2.com 80`)

Comment: Also, if you hadn't chosen to hide the actual domain names, some people here might already have found the answer for you...

Comment: Thanks, Via Telnet, the 2nd site: Connection refused. 1st site, connects. @JennyD I've no problem sharing the domain names, I thought it conducive to good practice and not looking like spam to obscure them. :)

Comment: The working domain is http://reefbase.co.uk the non-working domain is http://epints.com They both resolve to the same server IP. Thanks.

Comment: And when you used telnet, did you see the same IP address being used in both cases?

Comment: I thought I did. 1 digit out. As per your answer, thank you. :'( :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two domains do **not** resolve to the same IP.

```
[jenny@temeraire ~] $ dig epints.com A

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;epints.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
epints.com.     300 IN  A   198.23.203.161


[jenny@temeraire ~] $ dig reefbase.co.uk A

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;reefbase.co.uk.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
reefbase.co.uk.     300 IN  A   198.23.203.162
```

This is the reason why hiding the domain names is a bad thing...

If the two hostnames **had** resolved to the same IP, it would have been literally impossible for Apache to not respond to only one of them. It would, however, have been possible for e.g. a filtering reverse proxy or firewall to block packages containing one of the hostnames; this is why telnet is such a useful tool since it shows you every step of the communication in a way that a browser doesn't.

Comment: I feel silly now. I really wasn't being obscure. I thought it was the etiquette to use example domains rather than actual domains. Thanks for your help. I didn't spot that. The IP ending 162 is correct and that has a VHost ready and waiting for an incoming request from the non-working domain. I'll go fix that typo in my DNS.

Comment: @i-CONICA It's unfortunate that so many people think this is the right thing to do... I've tried to get a change into the [help] to clarify this, but it's not met with success so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add NameVirtualHost directive to run multiple vhost on same IP address.
Add below line before your VirtualHost begins.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: Tried this, upon restarting apache: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release.

Comment: Is both domain pointed to same IP? If domain points to different IP's, make sure that incoming HTTP traffic is allowed to 2nd IP address in IPTABLES/firewall..... as well as check if there any .htaccess in 2nd vhosts's Document root which has any bad directive..

Comment: Hi, In the DNS both domains resolve to the same IP. If you trace a request to both domains, both end up at the same IP. Yet only the first setup domain responds to requests. The 2nd does not get a response at all. A .htaccess error would give a 500 at least. It'd give something. The server doesn't even accept a connection when the request comes from that domain name.